# Определите количество цепочек длины 4, где все четыре символа различны

Tags: python

Скачайте текстовый файл, состоящий не более чем из 106 символов A, B, C и D.
Определите количество цепочек длины 4, где все четыре символа различны.
Не очень понимаю как проверять сразу длину цепочки и количество символов, идея была примерно такая:

```
file = open("24.14.txt")
line = file.readline()
count = 0
maxx_summ = 0
for i in range(len(line)-1):
    if line[i] != line[i+1] and line[i+1] != line[i+2] and line[i+2] != line[i+3]:
        count += 1
        maxx_summ = max(maxx_summ,count)
    else:
        count = 1
 print(maxx_summ)
```

Comment: Я бы в цикле брал срез длиной в четыре символа, превращал бы его в set() и смотрел на длину получившегося множества. Если она не равна четырем, значит в этот срезе есть повторы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ты внутри цикла используешь
   `line[i]`, `line[i+1]`, `line[i+2]`, `line[i+3]`
   Следовательно тебе нужно убедиться, что `i + 3` не превышает `len(line) - 1`.
   Получается нужно уменьшить длину цикла до `len(line) - 3`
2. Для того, чтобы проверить, что у тебя все символы различны, можно использовать set
   `{line[i], line[i+1], line[i+1], line[i+3]}` и проверить, что количество элементов в этом сете равна 4
3. У тебя счетчики `count` и `maxx_summ` используются примерно для одного и того же, можно обойтись одним

в итоге, если модифицировать твой код, получится

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(line)-3):
    if len({line[i], line[i+1], line[i+2], line[i+3]}) == 4:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: `{line[i], line[i+1], line[i+2], line[i+3]}` -> `{*line[i:i + 4]}`. Или -> `set(line[i:i + 4])`.

Comment: Да, я согласен с тем, что эту строчку можно записать более эффективно. Я старался не вводить новые конструкции без необходимости, чтобы не увеличивать сложность задачи для автора.

Comment: Эффективность у всех трёх вариантов одинаковая. Я говорил только про компактность записи.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy хм... как то в этом варианте диапозон генератора не верен. Правильно: range(len(line)-3)

Answer (score 2):

рефакторинг... рефакторинг...

```
#with open("24.14.txt") as file:
    #line = file.readline().strip()
line = '123456'

count = sum(len(set(line[i:i + 4])) == 4 for i in range(len(line)-3))

print(count)

>>>3
```

Благодаря мистеру @Spatz, обратим внимание на то, что при чтении строки из файла, к ней будет добавлен '\n'. Поэтому необходимо обработать строку `strip()` - это удалит в конце строки '\n'.
[Справка по strip().](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)

Answer (score 1):

Опираясь на комментарий выше, вот такой код бы получился.

```
with open("24.14.txt") as file:
    line = file.readline()

count = 0

for i in range(0, len(line), 4):
    current_piece = line[i:i + 4]
    if len(set(current_piece)) == 4:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Берем срезы по 4 символа, делаем из среза множество (структура данных, где все элементы уникальны). Если длина множества равна 4, значит в срезе было 4 разных символа и его нужно посчитать.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` - вы вернёте единицу. А должна быть двойка.

Comment: C чего должна быть двойка?

Comment: `(1, 2, 3, 4)` - все разные, `(2, 3, 4, 5)` - все разные.

Comment: А, точно. My bad. Тогда надо через индексы интегрировать. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно решение которое я придумал, без исправлений, правда с точки зрения нормально программиста оно ужасно):

```
file = open("24.14.txt")
line = file.readline()
count = 0
maxx_summ = 0
for i in range(len(line)-3):
    if (line[i] != line[i+1] and line[i] != line[i+2] 
        and line[i] != line[i+3]) and (line[i+1] != line[i+2] and line[i+1] != line[i+3]) and (line[i+2] != line[i+3]):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Небольшая ошибка в диапазоне генератора, правильно: ```range(len(line)-3)```

Answer (score 0):

Извлекаем из строки все возможные куски длины `k`, превращаем их в множество, размер множества сравниваем с `k`, если равенство, увеличиваем счётчик:

```
def count_set_substrings(s, k):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s) - k + 1):
        if len(set(s[i:i + k])) == k:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Тоже самое но в более питоническом стиле:

```
def count_set_substrings(s, k):
    return sum(1 for i in range(len(s) - k + 1) if len(set(s[i:i + k])) == k)
```

Если длина строки и длина подстроки могут быть большими, то предложенные решения не самые быстрые. Время работы пропорционально `(N - K)K`, где `N` - длина строки, `K` - длина проверямых подстрок. Можно сделать лучше.

Заведем словарь, в котором будем хранить символы и их количество. Первоначально словарь заполняется первыми `K` символами строки. Затем символы обрабатываются парами: один вставляется, один удаляется. Если размер словаря достигает `K` прибавляем единицу к счётчику. Пример:

> ```
> строка и          операции   словарь со                  размер
> указатели                    счётчиками букв             словаря
> |A B C D D C B A             {                      }    0
> [A]B C D D C B A    +A       {A: 1                  }     1
> [A B]C D D C B A    +B       {A: 1, B: 1            }      2
> [A B C]D D C B A    +C       {A: 1, B: 1, C: 1      }       3
> [A B C D]D C B A    +D       {A: 1, B: 1, C: 1, D: 1}        4
>  A[B C D D]C B A    -A +D    {      B: 1, C: 1, D: 2}       3
>  A B[C D D C]B A    -B +C    {            C: 2, D: 2}      2
>  A B C[D D C B]A    -C +B    {      B: 1, C: 1, D: 2}       3
>  A B C D[D C B A]   -D +A    {A: 1, B: 1, C: 1, D: 1}        4
> ```

В каждой итерации цикла словарь обновляется за константу. Общая сложность программы будет `N`. От `K` время работы не зависит:

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bag = {}

    def add(self, v):
        self._bag[v] = 1 + self._bag.get(v, 0)

    def remove(self, v):
        if self._bag[v] == 1:
            del self._bag[v]
        else:
            self._bag[v] -= 1

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._bag)


def count_set_substrings(s, k):
    it1 = iter(s)
    bag = Bag()
    for c1 in itertools.islice(it1, k):
        bag.add(c1)

    count = 0
    if len(bag) == k:
        count += 1

    it2 = iter(s)
    for c1, c2 in zip(it1, it2):
        bag.add(c1)
        bag.remove(c2)
        if len(bag) == k:
            count += 1

    return count
```